# Is there an iOS keyboard that writes a blank after a comma?

Tags: ios, keyboard

I haven't found a single keyboard app yet which comes with that handy option.
Already tried Gboard and SwiftKey.

SwiftKey for Android can do it, but not the iOS app.

Comment: Did you try using Settings app → General → Keyboard → Text Replacement?

Comment: @NimeshNeema unfortunately this function isn't replacing autamatically. So have to tap on the suggested replacement. This is like tapping on the blank for me. But tahnks for that!